# Showing SQL Server Report through the Web

Tags: sql, sql-server, web

I have been reading tons of different articles, but for some reason, Im not able to get a straight answer for my question.

Question:
In SQL Server Report, Can I expose reports to users through the internet without embedding it inside an app using the ReportViewer Control? (I know i can use ReportViewer Control, Its pretty awesome and its definitely an option, I got it working great).

This part is fuzzy to me, in my mind, I want to give the user the web address of the report,
they login with a username and password and then they look at their reports.

Is that possible? Every time i read something related to it, they are talking about intranets and not the internet.

Any input would be appreciated.

Comment: "intranets and not the internet" This is more a deployment decision than anything. [This](http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-BTsjsOeiYCc/Tt7PLw-H_5I/AAAAAAAAAbw/8llXnHZCvaA/s1600/ReportManager2.png) could easily be www.yoursite.com/Reports

Comment: authentication happens before the web server sends the response (which would contain your report) - i've setup windows auth on internet web sites and it works.  To make sure passwords do not go in clear text I disabled port 80 (https only)

Comment: Todda - That is exactly what i want, but doesnt seem to work in your example, i didnt get login screen or anything.
also are you able to set input parameters, filtering and searching in reports that are viewed through the report manager?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes,

Reporting services installs a site in IIS which if configured correctly can be viewed via the web. This is known as the report manager. It has built in roles to restrict users to view only if necessary.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms157147.aspx

Comment: Ah thanks, yea i always ran into it, I just couldnt find a decent tutorial. Just have to install and play around with admin till i get the right roles to work. Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is what you are looking for, [Pass parameters and options with a URL in SQL Reporting Services](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1336/pass-parameters-and-options-with-a-url-in-sql-reporting-services/).

It's also possible to have the application call a report on behalf of the user and deliver a PDF or other rendered output. See [ReportExecutionService Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc282506.aspx) and [ReportExecutionService.Render Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/reportexecution2005.reportexecutionservice.render.aspx).